# Need PHP related clarification

Tags: php, angular

I have the following code written in a file name "backend_user.php"

## CODE 1:

```php
<?php
require_once '_db.php';

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$params = json_decode($json);

class Result {}

$response = new Result();
if ($user != null) {
    $response->result = 'OK';
    $response->user = $user['name'];
    $response->message = 'Success';
}
else {
    $response->result = 'Unauthorized';
    $response->message = 'Invalid token';
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

The above code gets called by the code below stored in data.service.ts in Angular

## CODE 2:

```
getUser(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post("/api/backend_user.php", {}).pipe(map((response:any) => {
    this.user = response.user;
    return response;
  }));
}
```

As you can see from above code, nothing gets passed in the request body. But in CODE 1, there is a variable named `$user` referred.

From where does `$user` get it's value from?

Can somebody clarify?

Answer (score 0):

`$user` is just the response value. It's kind of like an arrow function in javascript so you can rename `$user` to `$foo` and do `$foo['name']` and it will still work.

`$user` is just the given variable name for the response. So, `$user['name']` is accessing `HttpResonse.name` effectively. `name` is just a property on the response.